# How to link Google app to GCP project, as required for integrity api standard request

Tags: google-play-integrity-api

During integration with Google integrity api, I am not able to get the verdict result using standard token, but can do it with classic token(shorter one), here is the error:

POST https://playintegrity.googleapis.com/v1/com.sofi.mobile:decodeIntegrityToken
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "You are not authorized to decode the requested integrity token.",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

It does not appear clearly how to link the app to Service account under gcp project, according to https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/standard

Create a service account within the Google Cloud project that's linked to your app. During this account creation process, you need to grant your service account the roles of Service Account User and Service Usage Consumer.

Anyone has any ideas?

Expect no 403 error.